# MySQL dictionary query optimization

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, optimization

I have a dictionary query which I would like to optimize. Apparently the query is too long as the result page takes quite long to load. The query is as follows:

```sql
$var = @$_GET['q'] ;
$varup1 = strtoupper($var);
$varup = addslashes ($varup1);

$query1 = "select distinct $lang from $dict WHERE
UPPER ($lang) LIKE trim('$varup')
or UPPER($lang) LIKE replace('$varup',' ','')
  or replace($lang,'ß','ss')  LIKE trim('$varup')
or replace($lang,'ss','ß')  LIKE trim('$varup')
or replace($lang,'ence','ance')  LIKE trim('$varup')
or replace($lang,'ance','ence')  LIKE trim('$varup')
or UPPER ($lang) like trim(trailing 'LY' from '$varup')
or UPPER ($lang) like trim(trailing 'Y' from '$varup')
or UPPER ($lang) like trim(trailing 'MENTE' from '$varup')
or UPPER ($lang) like trim(trailing 'EMENT' from '$varup')
or UPPER ($lang) like trim(trailing 'IN' from '$varup')
```

The purpose is that a search string shall also find different writings of the same word or the adverb of an adjective.

The table looks like

[image: table English German]

or

[image: table English Spanish]

For instance "flawlessly" shall also display "flawless". "Fully" shall also find "full" and vice-versa.

"Feliz" should also find the entries for "Felizmente".

There are around twenty substitutes like the above which I eliminated as they do not make the question easier to understand.

The whole code is quite long and I wonder if I can make it smaller without losing functionality. Any ideas?

Comment: To be able to use the index you need the conditions to be in the form `field = complicated_expression`. `UPPER(field) = something` can't use an index. A case insensitive collation will remove the need for `UPPER`, but for the other cases you will need to have multiple entries or some other type of processing.

Answer (score 1):

Where is the `FROM` clause in the query?

The `REPLACE` calls could be chained:  `REPLACE(REPLACE(..., 'a', 'b'), 'c', 'd').  Ditto for the`TRIM` calls.

As already mentioned, a suitable `COLLATION` eliminates all need for `UPPER()` and `LOWER()`.  Avoid the `...general...` collations, and you will be provided with this: `ss`=`ß`.  Many, but not all, treat `ij`=`ĳ` and/or `oe`=`œ` and/or `Aa`=`Å` (etc); do you need them, too?  Here is a rundown of most situations:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/utf8_collations.html

Using a `FULLTEXT` index will take care of *most* of the endings you are testing for, there obviating most of your code.

You show multiple words in the second column.  Is this simply for display?  If you need to pick apart the words, then you have other nasty challenges.

This, alone, will speed up the query something like 10-fold:

```
WHERE english LIKE 'ha%'
  AND ... (whatever else you have)
```

That is, filter on the first 2 letters with something that can use `INDEX(english)`, specifically `LIKE 'ha%'` for the word `hate`.  Since you seem to be using PHP, there should be no difficulty building this into the query.

Here's another thought on my `substring($word, 0, 2)`...  Instead of specifially using "2", see if `floor(strlen($word)/2)` will work well enough.  So, 'flawlessly' would be tested `LIKE 'flawl%'` and run a lot faster than even 10-fold.

But, another issue.  Are you chopping both the word in the table and the word given?  Try to avoid chopping the word in the table.  To discuss this further, please provide the table entries for 'flaw', 'flaws', 'flawless', flawlessly', etc.  I can't quite tell if you need to get all the way down to 'flaw', but have various rows for the various forms.

Beware of some very short words with odd forms.  Perhaps you need to add extra entries to avoid making the SQL query too messy.  These change the *second* letter: "LIE" and "LYING".  Seems like there is even a common word that changes the *first* letter.

Comment: Of course there was a "from" in the query. I omitted it by accident when I extracted it for the example. Well in the case of "flaw*" there are not so many entries. There are "flaw", "flawing", "flawless", "flawlessness". There are other cases where the query is muy trickier. For instance I do not want that if the user looks for "copy" that it lists also the translation of "cop", which obviously does not make sense. There are no comma-separated entries in the table. It was just to show what it contains. Each translation comes in a separate cell.Thanks for all the hints.

Comment: @user9 - It is a nontrivial problem, especially in English, which has words 'borrowed' from so many diverse languages.